# Using vim for creating fixed width text?

Tags: vim, text-editors, gvim

I've got text in the form

```
xxxx  yyyyy
xx yyyy
xxxxxxxx  yyyyy
x y
```

I'd like the second set in each line to begin at the same point ie

```
xxxx      yyyyy
xx        yyyy
xxxxxxxx  yyyyy
x         y
```

I can't think of an elegant solution using vim and it always bothers me when I invest more time in a solution than it would take to just manually do something.. Can always bank it for next time if anyone's got a clever one!

Comment: What OS are you using? Does it _need_ to be a vim solution or will an external tool do?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen some clever find/replacement tricks that would get the job done but I can't for the life of me commit them to memory so this is one thing I use *(and recommend)* a plugin.

Using [Align](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align.git), this becomes be a mere

```
- VG                (select all)
- <leader>tsp       (align whitespace)
```

From the help

```
    ---------------------------         *alignmap-Tsp*
    Alignment Map Examples: \tsp            *alignmap-tsp* {{{3
    ---------------------------

    Normally Align can't use white spaces for field separators as such
    characters are ignored surrounding field separators.  The \tsp and
    \Tsp maps get around this limitation.

    Original: >
     one two three four five
     six seven eight nine ten
     eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen
<
    Becomes: Select the lines, \tsp >
     one    two    three    four     five
     six    seven  eight    nine     ten
     eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen
<
    Becomes: Select the lines, \Tsp >
        one    two    three     four    five
        six  seven    eight     nine     ten
     eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen
<
```

Comment: Another similar plugin is [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/).

Comment: Easy Align is another one, I highly recommend it.